# Store one column value when querying select *

Tags: sql, sql-server

`tableB` has 3 columns: `X Y Z`

I want to get all rows and store the value of one column to use it in further SQL queries. How can I achieve this?

```sql
DECLARE @Y INT

SELECT * @Y = Y 
FROM tableB
```

This doesn't work, because I am doing `select *` here, but I want to read all rows and store the value of one column using a single query.

PricingDriver
(
PricingDriverId int,
Driver1 int,
Driver2 int
)

DriverConsumer
(
DriverConsumerID int,
PricingDriverId int,
poolcode string,
poollevel int
)

I want to read all columns PricingDriver and use the PricingDriverId to query driverconsumer table.

I can achieve this  -

```
declare @PricingDriverId int

select * from PricingDriver

select @PricingDriverId = PricingDriverId from PricingDriver

select * from DriverConsumer where PricingDriverId = @PricingDriverId
```

But I want to do it in single query on PricingDriver

Comment: You'd need to load it into a table variable. Can you exaplain what you are trying to do in more detail?

Comment: How do you imagine being able to store the values of **all rows** for a single column into a **single variable**?

Comment: You need to give us a bit more context? You want to display all the rows? But to pull all the values of even one column still requires a table, unless the value is the same for every row.

Comment: 1) Why do you want to make it a single query? 2) Your query doesn't work if there are multiple rows in `PricingDriver` because this `select @PricingDriverId = PricingDriverId from PricingDriver` will pick up one (random as it stands without a where clause) value.

Comment: >> `I want to read all columns PricingDriver and use the PricingDriverId to query driverconsumer table.`.  Typically what we do is use `JOIN` on both the tables. Example: `SELECT * FROM PricingDriver d INNER JOIN DriverConsumer c ON d.PricingDriverId = c.PricingDriverId`

Answer (score 1):

Should this work within subquery?

```
SELECT * FROM
    DriverConsumer
WHERE PricingDriverId IN 
    (SELECT PricingDriverId FROM PricingDriver)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

But what is the point, what are you trying to do?

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (MyCol VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @MyTable (MyCol)
SELECT Starter FROM dbo.Contest;

SELECT * FROM @MyTable


-- This is exactly the same as

SELECT * FROM (SELECT Starter FROM dbo.Contest) As T
```

Comment: please check description now

Comment: What you want is a basic SQL inner join. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Someone already answered. This is a classic xy problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem